# Regular Expression to detect start and end of pattern in a one line of string

Tags: regex, vb.net

**Problem:**
I want to create a regular expression that detects 'M' at the beginning and looks for '^' as the end. My problem is I want my regular expression to detect all instances in a single line of string only then output them.

**Example:**

String: M123456789^M123^C123^M1234^

The output should be:

1. M123456789^
2. M123^
3. M1234^

`Notice that I reject 'C123^' because it doesnt start on 'M'.`

So far I have here a regular expression that detects 'M', but I am having a problem on manipulating it.

Here's my code:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim str As String = "MLIVEOKK0S0^MRNS02K0S0^CKILL^"
    Console.WriteLine("Matching words that start with 'S': ")
    showMatch(str, "\b^\S*")
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub

Sub showMatch(ByVal text As String, ByVal expr As String)
    Console.WriteLine("The Expression: " + expr)
    Dim mc As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(text, expr)
    Dim m As Match
    For Each m In mc
        Console.WriteLine(m)
    Next m
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this pattern

"(M[^\^]+\^)"

Pattern breakdown:

- (M[^\^]+\^) - Capture group that starts with M and ends with ^

  - [^\^]+ - Matches one or more characters that are not ^

Code Sample:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Module Module1
    Public Sub Main()
        Dim data As String = "M123456789^M123^C123^M1234^"

        Dim m As Match = Regex.Match(data, "(M[^\^]+\^)")
        While m.Success
            Console.WriteLine(m.Groups(1))
            m = m.NextMatch()
        End While   
    End Sub
End Module
```

Results:

```
M123456789^
M123^
M1234^
```

[Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ofFRF5)

### Non-Regex

If Regex is too complicated to understand, here's a non-Regex approach

```
Imports System

Public Module Module1
    Public Sub Main()
        Dim data As String = "M123456789^M123^C123^M1234^"

        Dim mIndex = data.IndexOf("M")
        Dim caretIndex = data.IndexOf("^", mIndex + 1)

        While mIndex > -1
            If (caretIndex > -1)
                Console.WriteLine(data.Substring(mIndex, caretIndex - mIndex + 1))
            Else 
                Console.WriteLine(data.Substring(mIndex))
            End If

            ' Search for the next match
            mIndex = data.IndexOf("M", caretIndex)
            caretIndex = data.IndexOf("^", mIndex + 1)
        End While
    End Sub
End Module
```

[Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BLfJkt)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend this [**site**](http://www.rexegg.com/) to further read up on regular expressions. You could use the below:

```
Dim input As String = "M123456789^M123^C123^M1234^"
For Each m As Match In Regex.Matches(input, "M[^^]*\^")
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value)
Next
```

**Output**

```
M123456789^
M123^
M1234^
```

The regular expression first matches an "M", then uses a negated character class which matches any character except `^` "zero or more" times then finally looks for and matches the ending caret.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider a non-regex approach. Regex is fine when you really need it, but it is a "write-only" coding style and that can make future maintenance hard.

Try this LINQ approach instead:

```
Dim results =
    "M123456789^M123^C123^M1234^" _
        .Split("^"c) _
        .Select(Function (x) x + "^") _
        .Where(Function (x) x.StartsWith("M"))
```

I got the desired result:

[image: results]